# React updating state and accessing inside same function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Does the below code to update state and access in the same onCellClicked function look good ?
I have "fileStatus" and "fileType" as useState in my hook and "sharedData" is my context obj.

```
const onCellClicked = (e) => {
        if (e.data.status !== 'TO') {
            console.log(e);
            let fileType = (e.data.status === 'Y') ? 'O' : 'I';
            setCurrentFileStatus(e.data.status);
            setFileType(fileType);

            var tempObj = {};
            setCurrentFileStatus((fileStatus) => {
                setFileType((fileType) => {
                    tempObj.currentFileStatus = fileStatus;
                    tempObj.summaryDate = form.dateField;
                    tempObj.fileType = fileType;
                });             
            });
            setSharedData(tempObj); // I want to ultimately set my context object based on the state values
            console.log("tempObj = " + tempObj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like that there are some necessary business logic is going on, and looks fine overall, but I guess there are rooms for improvement. Btw you didn't elaborate on the context and business logic you are dealing with.

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: So based on grid row click, I want to capture some data from that row...update couple of my state variable ("fileStatus" and "fileType") and then I set my context object based on these state values...

I then redirect to another route and use the context object to make some api call...

Comment: Only thing which was looking strange to me was using both setCurrentFileStatus() and setFileType() twitce...first to set a value and then as callback.....And also the use of nested callback...so not sure if this sort of coding looks good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tempObj.fileType = fileType;

You are updating state variable in **mutable** way this is not recommended.

Why not do:

```
  ...... 
  let fileTypeLocal = e.data.status === 'Y' ? 'O' : 'I';
  let fileStat = e.data.status;
  setCurrentFileStatus(fileStat);
  setFileType(fileTypeLocal);

  setSharedData({
    currentFileStatus: fileStat,
    summaryDate: form.dateField,
    fileType: fileTypeLocal
  });
```

?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful answer...So it seems like we need to use a local variable...
e.g. for currentFileStatus, we cannot directly do setCurrentFileStatus(e.data.status)
But instead need to do in 2 lines like you have shown...
let fileStat = e.data.status;
setCurrentFileStatus(fileStat);

Comment: @copenndthagen You *can* do `setCurrentFileStatus(e.data.status)`. I only did this: `let fileStat = e.data.status`, because I am using fileStat at **two** places (so that I could reuse it). I was not sure why you had the nested calls, so I removed them and directly stored the object in context.

Comment: yes...for some reason, setting setCurrentFileStatus(e.data.status) and using it to set on context was not working (though I had used local object for context as well)...But not sure if it was that or some other silly error...Anyways, thanks a lot for your so very helpful answer...